# Rotating a 3D plot

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I am working on my lab assignment involving planes and lines. I am trying to create a 3D plot in Mathematica and rotate it using a slider with `Manipulate`.

Here's my current code:

```
line := ParametricPlot3D[{7 - 5 t, 2 - 9 t, -6 - 5 t}, {t, -2, 2}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thick, ColorFunction -> (BlueLevel[#3] &), 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}, {-15, 15}}, 
  ViewPoint -> {1, -1, 1}]

plane := 
 ContourPlot3D[
  5 x - 8 y + 2 z == 13, {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, {z, -15, 15}, 
  Mesh -> True, ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[#3] &), PlotPoints -> 50, 
  ViewPoint -> {1, -1, 1}, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]

(*vals = {82, 6, -5};*)
(*Show[line,plane,PlotRange->{{-15,15},{-15,15},{-15,15}}, ViewPoint-> \
vals] *)(*Plot them together*)

Manipulate[
 Show[line, plane, PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}, {-15, 15}}, 
  ViewPoint -> val], {{val, {10, 10, 10}, {-10, -10, -10, 1}}, 
  ControlType -> Slider, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
]
```

I did some research on the documentation of the `Manipulate` command [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) and found out that I need an "initial" value, max value and a "step".

When I plugged that into my code I got this error:

`"ControlType -> Slider is not supported for the variable \ specification {val}. ControlType -> InputField will be used instead."`

Is there a way to have a slider at the top and rotate the plot as you drag it to the right?

I also tried using `Animate[]` but it, unfortunately, came out very "janky" with the image rotating at 4 fps. I don't know if this is an issue on my end or is that how `Animate[]` works in general.

I am fairly new to Mathematica, so I would really appreciate any help or explanation of where I went wrong.

Thank you

edit:
I'm terribly sorry, I submitted the wrong part of my code. I am working with 2 kernels and I pasted from the wrong one.

Comment: `Slider` can be used only for a scalar (1D) value but your `val` is a (3D) vector. Use separate values for x, y, and z, for example `ViewPoint -> {valx, valy, valz}`, then separately add each of them as a slider.

Comment: @Domen Bom poskusu, Hvala ti :)

Comment: I tried this: `Manipulate[
 Show[line, plane, PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}, {-15, 15}}, 
  ViewPoint -> {valx, valy, valz}], {{valx, 82}, -100, 100, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{valy, 6}, -100, 100, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{valz, -5}, -100, 100, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]` and it works, but the animation of the plot rotation is not smooth at all, is there a way to "improve" that ?

Comment: :) First, you should use `Set` (`=`) instead of `SetDelayed` (`:=`) when defining `line` and `plane`. Second, since you are plotting a simple plane, you should really turn down the number of `PlotPoints` (just remove that option all together). These two changes should make the plot more responsive.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I got 2 more questions. [#1] I was using `SetDelayed` because I didn't want to show the line and the plane plot separately, but only in one plot, after removing the colon I get 3 plots. [#2] Is there a way to group up 3 sliders into one?

Comment: MIght sound stupid because there are 3 dimensions but I'm not using it anywhere else in the project, it's just to show that the angle is equal to 19deg

Comment: see also [Tutorial -- Interacting with 3D Graphics](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InteractiveGraphics3DInteraction.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Show` doesn't have `ViewPoint` or `PlotRange` options.
Set these in the *first* plot you put into the `Show` function.
`Show` only needs the first set, the 2nd plot will follow.

This should work.

```
line[x_, y_, z_] := 
  ParametricPlot3D[{7 - 5 t, 2 - 9 t, -6 - 5 t}, {t, -2, 2},
   ViewPoint -> {x, y, z},
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
   PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}, {-15, 15}},
   Boxed -> True,
   Axes -> True];

plane = ContourPlot3D[
   5 x - 8 y + 2 z == 13, {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, {z, -15, 15},
   Mesh -> True,
   ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[#3] &),
   PlotPoints -> 50];

Manipulate[Show[
  line[x, y, z], plane],
 {{x, 10}, -10, 10, 1},
 {{y, 10}, -10, 10, 1},
 {{z, 10}, -10, 10, 1}]
```

[image]

Note that I retained your `line` as a function, but extended it with 3 parameters, `line[_x,y_,z_]`.

You don't need `plane` as a function, as `line` controls `ViewPoint`.

Comment: We need to add the option [`PreserveImageOptions -> False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PreserveImageOptions.html) in `Manipulate[...]` to keep the view point connected with controls after manual interactions with graphics object. (+1)